# Runtime check failure #2 - Stack around variable was corrupted

Tags: c++, oop

I'm attempting  to make a program that will transpose a (2 X 2) matrix using a 2-Dimensional array. But besides the runtime failure I'm having an issue in inputting an integer value into the index [0][1], like the value of [1][0] is going into the index [0][1] as well as [1][0]. The value of [0][0] and [1][1] is as it was inputted by the cin keyword when asked during execution. I also didn't seem to receive any compilation errors that should be a worry to me either. Like I even added the stdio header as well, just in case that may somehow help or anything.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
using namespace std;
class transpose
{
    public:
        int m[1][1], te;
        void input();
        void process();
        void output();
};
void transpose::input()
{
    cout << "Matrix format:"<< endl << "[a b]" << endl << "[c d]" << endl;
    cout << "Enter a: ";
    cin >> m[0][0];
    cout << "Enter b: ";
    cin >> m[0][1];
    cout << "Enter c: ";
    cin >> m[1][0];
    cout << "Enter d: ";
    cin >> m[1][1];
    cout << "Entered matrix:" << endl << "[" << m[0][0] << " " << m[0][1] << "]" << endl;
    cout << "[" << m[1][0] << " " << m[1][1]<<"]" << endl;
}
void transpose::process()
{
    te = m[0][1];
    m[0][1] = m[1][0];
    m[1][0] = te;
}
void transpose::output()
{
    cout << "Transposed matrix:" << endl << "[" << m[0][0] << " " << m[0][1] << "]" << endl;
    cout << "[" << m[1][0] << " " << m[1][1] << "]";
}
void main()
{
    class transpose t;
    t.input();
    t.process();
    t.output();
    _getch();
}
```

The output I'm getting during execution (within debugging mode of VS 2013) is: http://screencloud.net/v/gbQP

### NB: The runtime error popup occurs after I press a character for the program to complete execution [i.e. after I press a key at the _getch() command].

I already tried searching for previous stack variable corruption examples but couldn't find a way to remove my error.

Comment: `int m[1][1]` - that's a 1x1 "matrix"...

Comment: I don't understand how that makes sense. I mean lets say we have variable:

int m[1]; but this has 2 index values of m[0] and m[1] right?

Comment: Then `m` is an array of one `int`. `m[1]` does not exist. Whether that makes sense or not is your problem - you wrote it :-)

Comment: And what would you say about the stack error popup?

Comment: Exactly what juanchopanza wrote. You're reading and writing past the bounds of your array. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: ok thanks! That fixed both issues

Comment: You should use `#include <iostream>` etc - the angle brackets mean standard headers, and quotes mean user-defined headers. And `main` returns `int`.

Comment: Ok, it's just I've seen tutorials using quotes for standard headers so I assumed it was possible to use it for all header files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix is 1 by 1, but you are using it as if it were 2 by 2:

```
m[0][1]; // only valid index is 0
```

This out of bounds access is *undefined behaviour*. You need to fix that.

Comment: Ok so would you suggest using int m[2][2]; in the declaration in that case?

Comment: @Khaleel78 Make it as big as you need it to be. If you need it to be 2 by 2, then yes, `m[2][2]`.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that then